# Accessing variables of an instance stored in an Object

Tags: java, arrays, object

I can't seem to access any get/set methods or the variables directly from an object. I'm attempting to get the level of my enemy which is stored in a variable as below. The last line, I 'want' to do "World[i][j].enemy.getLevel()" but apparently that is an illegal move? At the moment it just prints the objects id reference.

Is there a conversion back to an object i'm missing?

The Monster class extends Player.

Creation:

```
World[i][j].enemy = spawnEnemy(World[i][j].mapLevel); //Spawn a monster.
```

Other code:

```
    public static Object spawnEnemy(int level) {
    //Spawns a monster and returns the Object.
    Monster enemy = new Monster();
    enemy.setLevel(level);
    enemy.setMaxHealth(level * 5);
    enemy.setHealth(enemy.getMaxHealth());
    enemy.setDamage(enemy.getLevel() * 3);
    return enemy;
}

    public static void enemiesAlive() {

for (int i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++)
        {
        if (World[i][j].enemyAlive)
            {
            System.out.print(i + "-" + j + " with a level of " + World[i][j].enemy + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? This looks like a accessibility issue.

What is the error you get when you try .getLevel()?

Comment: It required a cast, since the Monster class extended Player it ended up being (Player).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The last line, I 'want' to do "World[i][j].enemy.getLevel()"

The problem is that you forgot the call to `getLevel()` and simply print the object reference.

Change

```
System.out.print(i + "-" + j + " with a level of " + World[i][j].enemy + ", ");
```

for

```
System.out.print(i + "-" + j + " with a level of " + ((Player)World[i][j].enemy).getLevel() + ", ");
```

Comment: I did try that first however, you got me on the right track and needed to cast it prior to accessing it with: System.out.print(i + "-" + j + " Level:" + ((Player) World[i][j].enemy).getLevel() + ", ");